# I can't figure out the problem with my code not showing expected results

Tags: c++

Write a program that gets two positive single digit integers from the user. Then
print all the numbers from 1 to 1,000 that are divisible by both of those integers.
Print ten numbers per line and separate them by a tab. ('\t')

I have done a code to print numbers from 1 - 1000 that are divisible by two numbers, x and y.

```
#include <iostream> using namespace std; int main() {

int x, y;
cout << "Enter two positives single digit integers: ";
cin >> x >> y;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        if ( i % x == 0 && i % y == 0)
            cout << i << '\t';
            if (i % 10 == 9)
            cout << endl;
        else i++;    
    }
    return 0; }
```

I'm not getting any results that I need for my code.
Expected results:

```
Enter two positive single digit integers: 5 6
30  60  90  120 150 180 210 240 270 300
330 360 390 420 450 480 510 540 570 600
630 660 690 720 750 780 810 840 870 900
930 960 990
```

Comment: I think you need to take a step back, and reread the chapter of your text-book about compound statements like loops and conditions. You have some extra semicolons that you shouldn't have.

Comment: ... and I would suggest to learn about debugging or "poor mans debugging" (putting cout statements in the right places)

Comment: @Marged i updated it. by accident i posted the old version of it. Im having trouble making the number go on a new line after 10 digits.

Comment: After 10 attempts or after 10 printed figures ?

Comment: After 10 printed numbers. I will update my post so you can see

Comment: Twin `i++`. Are you sure? `i % 10 == 9` makes new lines after 9 and then after each 10, starting from 19.

Comment: @S.M. Im getting the results but all the numbers are showing up on one line. They aren't going to second line after 10 times. Thats the part im stuck at.

Comment: Look at my comment carefully. You have twin `i++` if `i % 10 != 9` is true.

Answer (score 1):

The 'i%10 ==9' should be a 0 and not a 9 since you want that after a number divisible by 10 (meaning that there is no remainder) you end the line. Second iterating i in the for loop is wrong since this is what a for loop initially does. This is just some bad basics, try rereading c++ introduction books or watching more tutorials.